# Switch out a prepared wizard spell

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, wizard

What ways are there for a wizard to change out his prepared spells in a short rest?

P.S. I hope this isn't an replica, I looked around and only found this question for 5e.

Comment: What are the house rules that govern the effects of a *3.5e* short rest? That is, what other options are already available during a short rest in your campaign?

Comment: Yes, please define what you mean by short rest for 3.5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To begin with, the concept of a “short rest” doesn’t exist in 3.5e. I assume you just mean some relatively-brief amount of time without combat or other interruptions, as opposed to a full eight-hour night’s sleep.

The simplest approach is to just leave some spell slots unprepared when preparing your spells for the day. [You are then able to prepare them at any point thereafter with just 15 minutes (assuming you did not do this with more than a quarter of your slots).](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/arcaneSpells.htm#wizardSpellSelectionandPreparation) This is an extremely useful, and often forgotten, feature. However, this is not quite the same as “switching out” spells, since you have to have left the slot empty to begin with. [*Mnemonic enhancer*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mnemonicEnhancer.htm) also allows you to prepare new spells later in the day, though it’s limited to only 3 spell levels’ worth of spells, and again you need to have prepared it to benefit.

More directly what you seek, *Complete Mage* includes the spell *Rary’s arcane conversion*, which swaps one prepared spell for another. It’s a 6th-level spell, which makes it a fairly high-level trick. There is also *spell engine* in the same book, which as an 8th-level spell allows you to re-prepare **all** the spells you have prepared but not cast yet. The former is a full-round action, so you don’t even really need a rest, but the latter takes 10 minutes and is probably closer to what you had in mind. Worth noting: *spell engine* also costs 500 gp and 250 XP—which is more annoying than significant at that level, but still.

Other approaches require specific effort on the wizard’s part.

- The hathran prestige class from *Player’s Guide Faerûn* can spontaneously cast any spell of the same level or lower in their spellbook from a prepared spell slot several times per day, or at-will if inside Rasheman.
- The mage of the Arcane Order prestige class from *Complete Arcane* gains the ability to tap into a large shared repository of spells belonging to the Arcane Order. Useful both for swapping spells and for getting spells you don’t have in your spell book.
- The ultimate magus prestige class from *Complete Mage* or [this web preview of the same](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20061010a&page=3) gains abilities along these lines, since it is a “theurge” class for spontaneous and prepared arcane spellcasting.
- The magelord prestige class from *Lost Empires of Faerûn* or [this web preview of the same](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20050202a&page=2) gains the ability to spontaneously swap any prepared spell for any spell he has Spell Mastery for, and conveniently gives four Spell Mastery slots.
- The primal scholar prestige class from *Secrets of Xen’drik* gains the ability to use a spell slot spontaneously if usually a prepared spellcaster. Said spell slot can only be used for spells at least a level lower than the slot, though, and it’s limited per day how much you can do this.

Not mentioned are numerous ways of storing spells from one day to use later, ways to get spontaneous spellcasting as a wizard, or other related concepts. See [this handbook](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=7150) for more details; it provided many of the things in this answer, and has more ideas besides.

Comment: Do you mean the race or the class hathran?

Comment: @Simon  There's a race, too? (That is, likely intended is the prestige class hathran from *Player's Guide to Faerûn* 59-61.)